# How to manipulate value from a return string in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, string, variables

I have a variable that contains a return value.

Value:

```
Team ID:
111111
Founded:
Feb 13, 2014 By USER

Dispute Percentage:" 0%
Reputation: -
```

What I am looking to keep is stickly (11111) and save it back to the value teamID. How can I manipulate the return string to only store that value and delete the rest.

Comment: What is *stickly*? Are you asking how to parse the multi-line String and get "Team ID" value?

Comment: What in the world are you asking???  Show your code.

Comment: Returning a complex string like this is difficult to work with. See my answer below for an alternative!

Comment: Is the format always the same? That is, you will always have the string "Team ID:", followed by a new-line, followed by the value you want?

Comment: Did any of the proposed solutions below help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you can do something like this

```
String value = "Team ID:\n" + "19288568\n"
    + "Founded:\n" + "Feb 13, 2014 By MLGQA\n"
    + "\n" + "Dispute Percentage: 0%\n"
    + "Reputation: -\n";
System.out.println(value.split("\n")[1]);
```

Outputs

```
19288568
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your returned `String` seems somewhat complex to me, I would suggest returning a custom object (a bean) containing the information you want, each with its own field.

By doing that, you will have a quick access to any of the fields you want, by simply calling the appropriate *getter* method on the returned object.

For example:

```
public class MyContainer {

    private int teamID;
    private String foundationDate;
    private String foundator;
    private int disputePercentage;
    private int reputation;

    public MyContainer() {
        // Constructor code.
    }

    public int getTeamID() {
        return teamID;
    }

    public void setTeamID(int teamID) {
        this.teamID = teamID;
    }

    public String getFoundationDate() {
        return foundationDate;
    }

    public void setFoundationDate(String foundationDate) {
        this.foundationDate = foundationDate;
    }

    public String getFoundator() {
        return foundator;
    }

    public void setFoundator(String foundator) {
        this.foundator = foundator;
    }

    public int getDisputePercentage() {
        return disputePercentage;
    }

    public void setDisputePercentage(int disputePercentage) {
        this.disputePercentage = disputePercentage;
    }

    public int getReputation() {
        return reputation;
    }

    public void setReputation(int reputation) {
        this.reputation = reputation;
    }
}
```

And your original returning method would look to something like this:

```
public MyContainer returningMethod(Object args) {
    // Your code.

    MyContainer bean = new MyContainer();
    // Fill the container.
    return bean;
}
```

- I do not know the exact types of data you use, so feel free to adjust this example for your needs!